# Comparar data sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou precisando comparar data em um certo intervalo de tempo. Preciso pegar o campo `DAT_REPOT_REALZ` e verificar as datas entre HOJE e sete dias atrás. Preciso também contar o numero de V (visitante) e o numero de L (lider) e M (participante), na `query` que fiz não deu muito certo pois não tenho muita familiaridade com `sql`.

Vale salientar que estou utilizando o `MYSQL`.

Tentei fazer assim

```
select case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'V' then count(FLG_IDENT_PESSO) when 'M' then count(FLG_IDENT_PESSO) end from tbl_PRESENCA WHERE FLG_IDENT_PRESE = 'S' and DAT_REPOT_REALZ <= now()-7
```

A estrutura de minha tabela:

```
COD_IDENT_REUNI bigint(20) UN PK 
COD_IDENT_PESSO bigint(20) UN PK 
FLG_IDENT_PRESE char(1) //PODE SER S (presente) ou N (nao presente)
FLG_IDENT_PESSO char(1) // PODE SER V (visitantes) ou L (lider) ou ainda M (participante)
DAT_REPOT_REALZ datetime // É O DIA EM QUE FOI FEITO O REPORTE
```

Comment: Tu precisa usar um `BETWEEN` ou duas verificações no `WHERE` pra funcionar do jeito que você quer.

Comment: Como ficaria a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar **BETWEEN** e a função **DATE_SUB**

Seu where fica assim : `where DAT_REPOT_REALZ between DATE_SUB(now(), interval 7 day) and now()`

Segue um [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a574e/1/0) de exemplo .

Em relação ao count , você pode colocar um sum em um case

exemplo :

```
SUM(case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'V' then 1 else 0 end) as Visitantes
```

query completa :

```
    select sum(case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'V' then 1 else 0 end) as visitantes , 
    sum(case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'M' then 1 when 'L' then 1 else 0 end) as participantes 
  from tbl_PRESENCA where DAT_REPOT_REALZ between DATE_SUB(now(), interval 7 day) and now()
```

Comment: você é 10, justamente o que precisava

Comment: Aeew \o// ! Que bom que deu certo

Comment: so teria uma coisa para acrescentar porque o M pode ser L também, ou seja preciso contar se for M e se for L também, como ficaria ?

Comment: Mesma lógica Renan , vou editar a resposta , mas vc tem que colocar um SUM() com um case dentro dele ,  e depois adicionar 1 pra cada vez que a comparação é atendida e 0 no else .( pra resolver desse jeito , existem outras soluções)

Comment: Não você nao entendeu se o cara for lider ou se ele for participante terá que somar mais um, por exemplo tem 3 L e 2 M então terá 5 participantes

Comment: entendi !! então você tem que colocar mais um when , vou modificar de novo !

Answer (score 2):

É possível fazer assim:

```
select 
    count(COD_IDENT_PESSO); 
FROM 
    tbl_PRESENCA 
WHERE 
    DAT_REPOT_REALZ BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND 
    FLG_IDENT_PRESE = 'S';
```

O SQL acima vai retornar o número total de pessoas que estiveram presentes na reunião. Para contar separado, basta usa uma outra condição no WHERE

```
select 
    count(FLG_IDENT_PESSO); 
FROM 
    tbl_PRESENCA 
WHERE 
    DAT_REPOT_REALZ BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND 
    FLG_IDENT_PRESE = 'S' AND
    FLG_IDENT_PESSO = '?';
```

Onde '?' seria o que você quer procurar em especifico, V, M ou L

```
select 
    sum(case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'V' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Visitantes',
    sum(case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'L' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Lideres',
    sum(case FLG_IDENT_PESSO when 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Participantes',
FROM 
    tbl_PRESENCA 
WHERE 
    DAT_REPOT_REALZ BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND 
    FLG_IDENT_PRESE = 'S';
```

Ou tudo em um select, dividindo como foi citado na outra resposta.

Comment: Porque a ideia é contar a quantidade de participantes que esteve presente , então tenho a flag FLG_IDENT_PESSO e tenho a possibilidade no campo de colocar V que teria que contar, e L + M que preciso contar, ou seja irei contar o numero de visitantes, depois contar numero de lider e participante juntos.

Comment: Tenho também um campo FLG_IDENT_PRESE que pode colocar 'S' e 'N', preciso contar apenas os que tem FLG_IDENT_PRESE = 'S'

Comment: Poderia colocar a sua tabela (ou o SQL dela) na sua pergunta pra eu entender melhor?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, qualquer dúvida só perguntar aqui nos comentários

Comment: Juntamente na mesma query tem como fazer não ?

Comment: COM LEFT JOIN CONSIGO FAZER ISTO NAO ?

Comment: é possivel usar um UNION para juntar os selects, cada um com um where usando um  `FLG_IDENT_PESSO = '?'` diferente